# Android Notification timeout without using a service

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm developing a common library (external jar) that is being provided to different developers of android apps.

I have a function that will display a Notification.

I want to have the notification timeout after 30-90 seconds

I want to minimize the requirements for the app developers, so writing a common service, and having them adding it to their manifests is my least favorite option.

Is it safe to spawn a thread and keep a handle to the notification manager?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I question the user-friendliness of this concept. Notifications are meant to stick around. For short-term information, there are toasts. A notification that expires sounds frustrating - I'm imagining feeling my phone vibrate, then slowly turning it on, trying to click on a notification - and it disappears! Talk about teasing the user.

Comment: They don't go away, we want to change the text to a past verbage. Because there is a network connection being made, and if they don't respond to it, then we drop the connection.

Then if the click the notification later, we will initiate the connection from our device back to them.

Comment: So you're changing the notification based on an event (in this case, dropping the connection). Why don't you simply change the notification when that happens rather than doing some timer witchcraft on the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either let the developer handle the dismissal/update themselves, or you will have to supply some sort of component (`Service`, or a `BroadcastReceiver` to use with `AlarmManager`) to handle it for them. They will have to register that component, as you note.

> Is it safe to spawn a thread and keep a handle to the notification manager?

Not really. If the process is terminated during your time window, your thread is terminated along with it.